# Why isn't my "virtual" array working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

In this example : http://jsfiddle.net/stephane_klein/Cgn2c/1/

I would like create "virtual" array in "App.my_list2".

My code don't work, what can I do to fix it ? What is my issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Stephane

Comment: Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all that's required is to set the *content* property to anything (even just an empty array will do).  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cgn2c/2/

```
App.my_list2 = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    // the content propery is required, even if it's not used
    content: [],
    length: 8,
    objectAtContent: function(idx) {
        return "foobar";        
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.my_list2}}
        {{ this }}
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

> foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar foobar

Comment: Also he missed `.property()` for the `length` function in the original fiddle, this example directly uses 8, so its not needed.